# Modify/Delete datastore Index on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

My old web.xml was

```
<datastore-index kind="TBL" ancestor="false"> 
    <property name="Col1" direction="asc" /> 
    <property name="Col2" direction="desc" />
    <property name="Col3" direction="asc" />
    <property name="Col4" direction="asc" />
    <property name="Col5" direction="asc" />
    <property name="Col6" direction="asc" />
    <property name="Col7" direction="asc" />
    <property name="Col8" direction="asc" />                         
</datastore-index>
```

My New web.xml is

```
<datastore-index kind="TBL" ancestor="false"> 
    <property name="Col1" direction="asc" /> 
    <property name="Col2" direction="desc" />
    <property name="Col3" direction="asc" />
    <property name="Col4" direction="asc" />
    <property name="Col5" direction="asc" />
    <property name="Col6" direction="desc" />
    <property name="Col7" direction="asc" />
    <property name="Col8" direction="asc" />                         
</datastore-index>
```

Created index on server

```
TBL  
------------
Col2 ▲ , Col1 ▲ , Col6 ▼  
Col4 ▲ , Col1 ▲ , Col6 ▼  
Col5 ▲ , Col8 ▲ , Col1 ▲ , Col6 ▲ => I got error for this index
Col8 ▲ , Col1 ▲ , Col6 ▲   
Col1 ▲ , Col2 ▼ , Col3 ▲ , Col4 ▲ , Col5 ▲ , Col7 ▲ , Col8 ▲ 
Col1 ▲ , Col2 ▼ , Col3 ▲ , Col4 ▲ , Col5 ▲ , Col6 ▼ , Col7 ▲ , Col8 ▲ 
Col1 ▲ , Col7 ▲  
Col1 ▲ , Col6 ▲  
Col1 ▲ , Col6 ▼
```

I am getting index not found error for 3rd index. I want to modify direction for col6 in all index and set it to "desc".

### How can i do that? or how can i delete index?

Anybody?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the  `vacuum_indexes` command.

> http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Deleting_Unused_Indexes

This will work for both Java and Python apps. In fact, Java's appcfg.sh does not yet support this at all, so you'll need the Python SDK if you're running a Java app.

Comment: Starting with Java SDK 1.4.2 it can be done with appcfg.sh (without using Python SDK)

Comment: It also works with the Go SDK (which includes appcfg.py)

Answer (score 1):

My environment/process:

- I define and maintain (add, remove, etc) my indexes in a file called "datastore-indexes.xml".
- I build and deploy my WAR file, using the Maven task "mvn
  appengine:deploy".
- I deploy indexes with the "mvn appengine:deployIndex" task.

When I run these tasks, my build generates this directory "target\appengine-staging\WEB-INF\appengine-generated".

In this directory you will find an "index.yaml" file, with the indexes that were generated from your "datastore-indexes.xml" file.

```
1. Open the Google Cloud SDK Shell, and cd to the directory with the "index.yaml" file.

2. In the shell, type "gcloud datastore indexes cleanup index.yaml"

3. It will prompt you to continue, and it will further notice indexes in the Cloud Datastore, that are not defined in the local "index.yaml" file.

4. Here it will prompt you to delete these indexes.
```

I do not think you can update an index, only delete (an old) and add (a new) index.

Answer (score 0):

This can now (2019-02-06) be done with:

`gcloud datastore indexes cleanup <INDEX_FILE>`

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/datastore/indexes/cleanup

Comment: How do I recreate the index.yaml if I lost it? With empty one this would delete all the index.